# Cannot find a package in yum repo list

Tags: tomcat, centos, yum

I'm looking for tomcat-native (Centos 6)

```
$sudo yum install tomcat-native
No package tomcat-native available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

How do I update the yum repository list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Yum is configured to search for the default yum repositories and if it can't find the package in that repository, you need to specify the appropriate repository hosting the package. You could specify this using https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Managing_Yum_Repositories.html
The below articles might help you install tomcat-native
http://linuxfreaks.in/tomcat-native-library-apr-installation-on-centos/
http://blogoless.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-native.html